# Chart Row Source Not Updated with Requery

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a chart in my Access Report. It's row source is set to a Query object so I can change the chart data at run time. Below is how I update the chart data.

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("source_query").SQL = "my_query"
Me.my_chart.Requery
```

These two lines are in my report's Open event.

However, my chart displays nothing after Requery. That is if I let the code run by itself. If I put a break point at the Requery statement and pause there, I can see my chart updated in the end.

Why is that so? And how can I make the Requery working by itself?

I'm using Accessing 2013 for this database.

Thank you.

Comment: How is the chart supposed to be updated when you're using the same query? Or is there something else I'm not understanding?

Comment: @OverMind the chart displays data from my query. but my query is dynamic. it's updated according to the data I insert to another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out after searching around for days. Here I post my solution and hope it helps anyone else who encounters the same problem.

The Requery does not update my chart because Access runs the code asynchronously, sometimes.

My "source_query" is based on a table that gets data only at run time. However, the way I insert data to this table is:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "some insert query"
```

This insert query takes quite some time to run and Access executes the following before it completes.

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("source_query").SQL = "my_query"
Me.my_chart.Requery
```

As a result, my "source_query" gets nothing because my table is not ready yet.

So, the solution? Change the way to run insert query as below

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "some insert query"
```

This forces Access to complete the insert query before it moves on to the next line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to programmatically insert a small pause, but I would suggest you to change the row source or your chart to the sql string.

Another possibility is to, after changing the sql in the query, reassign the rowsource of your chart to the new query, therefor forcing the chart to requery with your latest sql statement.